# Proving statistical assertions?

Tags: statistics

Are these assertions True or False? I'm not quite sure how to go about proving or disproving them…

> If $X ∼ \text{Unif}[0, 2]$, then $E(\ln(X)) \le 0$.

> If $X ∼ \text{Unif}[0, 2]$, and $Y = 1[X \in (.5, 1)]$, then $\text{Var}(Y) = \dfrac3{16}$.

Comment: That $E(\ln (X))\leq 0$ follows immediately from Jensen's inequality since the logarithm is concave.

Answer (score 2):

The most easy way is to count the expected value 
$$E\left(ln(X)\right)= \int_0^2 ln(x).\frac{1}{2} dx \approx - 0.3.$$

For the second part $Y$ has discrete distribution with 
\begin{align}
P(Y=1) & = P(X \in (0.5,1)) = \frac{1}{4} \\
P(Y=0) & =\frac{3}{4}.
\end{align}
 So $EY=\frac{1}{4}$ and variance is 
$V(Y) = E(Y^2) - (EY)^2 = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{16}=\frac{3}{16}.$

Answer (score 1):

If it's a uniform distribution, then the mean of the distribution will be the expected value. So if $X \sim U[0,2]$, then $E(X) = 0$. Then remember what $ln(X)$ looks like: at $x=1$ it crosses the $x$-axis, and as $x$ tends to $0$, $ln(X)$ approaches $-\infty$. Now map $X \to ln(X)$ for $X\in[0,2]$. On the low end, it asymptotically approaches negative infinity. On the positive end, $ln(2)$ is about 0.69. So it's reasonably clear (yes, I am hand-waving) that $E(ln(X)) \leq 0$.

You could make a formal proof that for every $0.7 >ln(X) > 0$ there's some arbitrarily small $ln(X)$, so their average will be a negative.

For the second problem, just calculate the expected value, and then use the fact that $V(Y) = E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2$.

Comment: $EX=1$! Also your proof of $E(\ln(X)) \le 0$ is mathematically not correct since it is not hard to find a function that has the same boundary conditions and positive integral.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick demonstration of the first part without actually doing the integral,
note that $\ln x \leq x - 1$, with equality only at $x=1$.
Therefore
$$ \int_0^2 \frac 12 \ln x\; dx < \frac 12 \int_0^2 (x - 1) \; dx = 0.$$

For the second part, refer to iiivooo's answer.